# My 4 year old screaming in his sleep doing nap time

Tags: pre-schooler

My 4 year old son screams in his sleep doing nap time and has to be woking  up to stop him from doing so. He does that at night as well, at least once or twice most nights. I am getting worried about him. What do I do?

Comment: Hi, Kate, and welcome to the site. Please include more about the symptoms your child is showing. Does it happen at the same time every night (e.g. say, 50 minutes after he falls asleep)? Does he remember the episodes? How long do they last? When did they start? Does anyone else in the family have a sleep disorder (sleepwalking, etc.)? What happens if you don't wake him up? If the answers point to, say, night terrors, the advice we give here can be much more helpful. Thanks!

Comment: These seem to be night terrors, which are perfectly normal at this age. By all means discuss this with his doctor, but it is likely night terrors, which will dissipate naturally over time. Hang in there :)

Comment: Well, maybe his mind is disturbed where he becomes scared while having disturbed nightmares. Or another possibility is that he is not comfortable with the surrounding or the temperature around him while he is asleep. So try making sure that these facts above are alright and maybe he will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

A child screaming during sleep can be quite disturbing. If the child is actually screaming loudly and perhaps thrashing, it could be what is known as night terrors. During these episodes, the child is not actually awake, though they sometimes appear to be due to the sound and movements not usually found during a sleep cycle. Since the child is not awake, it can be very difficult to calm him. He is unaware of your presence, let alone your soothing voice or calming touch. Most children outgrow these episodes. In the meantime, go to your child, make sure he is unable to accidentally harm himself, such as falling out of bed or becoming too twisted in blankets. If the screaming is accompanied by head banging, make sure the child's head is hitting nothing other than a soft pillow. You can speak calmly, try soft music, or touch a hand to provide comfort. Do not try to wake the child. This can be confusing to the child and your inability to fully wake him may cause further agitation. Before bed, make sure his environment is calming and the child is relaxed. This may help him fall asleep more comfortably and remain in the calmer state. Aromatherapy can be tried. Avoid large meals or exercise right before bed. Perhaps a story or lullaby will help the child to start out relaxed, with the hope of staying that way and minimizing the terrors. They will pass. Remain patient and don't panic.